# Paragraph break adjustment

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I've been encountering an issue regarding the spacing between paragraphs:

[image]

In this particular page, as there is a new section starting right on the next page, the paragraphs are stretched in order to fill more of the page. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Use the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`). However be aware that all pages will not necessarily have the same height.

Comment: Or you can insert `\clearpage` before the new section, I think. But if you do this, only do it when the document is otherwise finalised.

Comment: Or even put `\vfill` between the paragraph and the heading.